# Binary Encoding/Decoding File in Golang Gives Different Checksum

Tags: go, encoding, binary

I'm working on encoding and decoding files in golang.  I specifically do need the 2D array that I'm using, this is just test code to show the point.  I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong, I'm attempting to convert the file into a list of uint32 numbers and then take those numbers and convert them back to a file. The problem is that when I do it the file looks fine but the checksum doesn't line up.  I suspect that I'm doing something wrong in the conversion to uint32.  I have to do the switch/case because I have no way of knowing how many bytes I'll read for sure at the end of a given file.

```golang
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
)

const (
    headerSeq = 8
    body      = 24
)

type part struct {
    Seq  int
    Data uint32
}

func main() {
    f, err := os.Open("speech.pdf")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer f.Close()

    reader := bufio.NewReader(f)
    b := make([]byte, 4)
    o := make([][]byte, 0)
    var value uint32
    for {
        n, err := reader.Read(b)
        if err != nil {
            if err != io.EOF {
                panic(err)
            }
        }

        if n == 0 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("len array %d\n", len(b))
        fmt.Printf("len n %d\n", n)
        switch n {
        case 1:
            value = uint32(b[0])
        case 2:
            value = uint32(uint32(b[1]) | uint32(b[0])<<8)
        case 3:
            value = uint32(uint32(b[2]) | uint32(b[1])<<8 | uint32(b[0])<<16)
        case 4:
            value = uint32(uint32(b[3]) | uint32(b[2])<<8 | uint32(b[1])<<16 | uint32(b[0])<<24)
        }
        fmt.Println(value)
        bs := make([]byte, 4)
        binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(bs, value)
        o = append(o, bs)
    }
    fo, err := os.OpenFile("test.pdf", os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer fo.Close()

    for _, ba := range o {
        _, err := fo.Write(ba)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I have no way of knowing how many bytes I'll read for sure at the end of a given file." Well, there's your problem. PutUint32 always produces four bytes, but you don't always consume four bytes when reading. You have no reason to expect the file content to be identical after a round-trip.

Comment: Also note that bufio.Reader.Read is allowed to read as many bytes as will fit in the argument _or less_. It is by no means required to read four bytes every time. Use [binary.Read](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Read) or [io.ReadFull](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadFull) instead.

Comment: Is there a better way to do that conversion back into a byte array then?  It's not 100% necessary that the files be the same but I would certainly like for them to be.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to write and read arrays of varying length in a file.

```golang
import "encoding/binary"

// You need a consistent byte order for reading and writing multi-byte data types
const order = binary.LittleEndian

var dataToWrite = []byte{ ... ... ... }
var err error

// To write a recoverable array of varying length
var w io.Writer
// First, encode the length of data that will be written
err = binary.Write(w, order, int64(len(dataToWrite)))
// Check error
err = binary.Write(w, order, dataToWrite)
// Check error

// To read a variable length array
var r io.Reader
var dataLen int64
// First, we need to know the length of data to be read
err = binary.Read(r, order, &dataLen)
// Check error
// Allocate a slice to hold the expected amount of data
dataReadIn := make([]byte, dataLen)
err = binary.Read(r, order, dataReadIn)
// Check error
```

This pattern works not just with `byte`, but any other fixed size data type. See [`binary.Write`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#Write) for specifics about the encoding.

If the size of encoded data is a big concern, you can save some bytes by storing the array length as a **varint** with [`binary.PutVarint`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#PutVarint) and [`binary.ReadVarint`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/binary#ReadVarint)

Comment: Interesting, I think the last bit is most useful.  Binary reading/writing it's that big of a deal, I specifically need to convert the data into a series of uint32, transmit those, and then reassemble them elsewhere back into a file.  Meaning the file _must_ be a sequence of uint32.  I can't really explain the why unfortunately just yet.